# Vitual host for two separate project with same domain name

Tags: virtualhost

I have two projects. One is main project and another one is separate module project.I want to configure virtual host for both using same domain with sub-directory structure.

For Example : www.example.com pointing to one main project while www.example.com/submodule as another independent project.

My two virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin it@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/mainproject/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    ServerName dev-test.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /var/www/mainproject/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Submodule virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin it@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    ServerName dev-test.example.com
Alias /module /var/www/example/
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /var/www/example/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Anything wrong in this?

Answer (score 0):

I merged into single My virtual host file .My code :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin it@example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/docroot
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    ServerName dev-test.example.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    <Directory /var/www/example/docroot/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /module/ "/var/www/example2/"
    <Directory "/var/www/example2/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```